# Can I edit the source code of a wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to wordpress (just opened a test site few hours ago).
As part of a Proof Of Concept I'm conducting, I've been looking for some plugins.
I was able to find a plugin which does 95% of what I need to accomplish.

My question is - can I edit its source code? If that's matters, I'm talking about a plugin which I'm buying.

I'll appreciate your answers.

Thanks,
Nadav

Comment: in general, yes. but it will be hard to update afterwards

Comment: Besides updates? Are there any other things which I have to consider?

Comment: In addition, does the language is PHP?

Comment: the language is php. there shouldn't be any other issues besides updates